# The standard error of the mean

Tags: mean-square-error

I came across this formula for the standard error of the mean in a book and wondered how I might be misunderstanding it?

$$\widehat{SE} = \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{(x_i-\bar{x})^2}{n(n-1)}}$$

I would have thought it should be

$$\widehat{SE} = \frac{\sigma_x}{\sqrt{n}}$$

Could it be that the above refers the variance of the mean rather than the standard error? Is the standard error the same as the standard deviation?

Where is $\sigma_x$ is the standard deviation of the sample:

$$\sigma_x = \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{(x_i-\bar{x})^2}{n}}$$

Comment: Welcome to Math Stackexchange! Could you please define $\sigma_x$ ?

Comment: If you use $\sigma_x = \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{(x_i-\bar{x})^2}{n-1}}$, then your two expressions for $\widehat{SE}$ are equal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first formula
$$\widehat{SE} = \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{(x_i - \bar x)^2}{n(n-1)}}$$ is a point estimator of the standard error of the sample mean.  It is a statistic, and it estimates the standard error.

The true standard error of the sample mean is $$SE = \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}},$$ where $\sigma$ is the population standard deviation, and $n$ is the sample size.  This is because for independent and identically distributed $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ with common variance $\sigma^2$,
$$\operatorname{Var}[\bar X] = \operatorname{Var}\left[\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i\right] \overset{\text{iid}}{=} \frac{1}{n^2} \sum_{i=1}^n \operatorname{Var}[X_i] = \frac{1}{n^2} \cdot n \sigma^2 = \frac{\sigma^2}{n}.$$  Thus the standard deviation of the sampling distribution of the sample mean--i.e., the standard error--is $$SE = \sqrt{\operatorname{Var}[\bar X]} = \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}.$$  But $\sigma$ is a parameter.  If it is unknown, then we can only estimate the standard error through observing a sample.  This is why the first equation is $\widehat{SE}$ instead of $SE$.

The notation $\sigma_x$ is sometimes used to denote the sample standard deviation
$$\sigma_x = \sqrt{\frac{1}{n-1} \sum_{i=1}^n (x - x_i)^2}.$$
So both expressions are equivalent.